# How can I pass a variable as the value for jQuery .attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) what would be the proper syntax to pass a variable in as the value.  What I am trying to do is :

```
var under700 = 'image.jpg'

$('.two_images img').attr('src', (under700) );
```

### Edit

Judging from the responses, I may have oversimplified this.  Here is the rest of the function if that adds any clarity.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     function imageresize() {
         var contentwidth = $('#two_up').width();
         var under700 = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>&w=340'
         if ((contentwidth) < '700'){
     // I also tried defining the variable here
             $('.two_images img').attr('src', under700 );
             } else { 
     // this one works fine
             $('.two_images img').attr('src','<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>');
             }
     }
 imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads     
 $(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized
 imageresize();
});
```

Comment: This should work. You can omit the brackets around `under700`.

Comment: just make sure variable is defined within same visibility context

Comment: try adding your code inside the `document ready` block, just in case...

Comment: Is that code copied and pasted exactly from your code?

Comment: @Richard.. I left out one line.. adding it now the $(window).bind event.  I dont think this is related because I tried this outside of the function and when I check source it still is just writing the variable name

Comment: Thanks everyone for your ideas and input.. I need to go to sleep.  Later I will see if using latest version of jquery (it is currently using 1.4.4) helps

Comment: due to jquery versioning, in some cases instead of using attr() we should use prop()

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.two_images img').attr('src', under700);
```

Don't need the inner brackets, although they won't stop it working.

Comment: I tried that first.. it just prints that.. it doesn't pass the variable

Comment: Thanks..  I should have put the complete function to start with.. something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the code without the php? It looks like you might have some issues with too many single quotes on that line, but it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the document.

Try replacing the php echos with just plain strings, eg: `var under700 = '123';`, and make sure you end the variable declaration line with a semi colon, it looks like that might be missing too, and can cause odd errors.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried 123 (and ;), but same thing it just prints under700.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is wrong:

```
if ((contentwidth) < '700'){
```

jQuery's `width()` function returns an integer, so you don't need the quotes around the `700`:

```
if(contentwidth < 700) {
```

Try that.

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(under700)` and `console.log(contentwidth)`, just to see if they are what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  // declare early
  function imageresize() {
    var contentwidth = $('#two_up').width();
    // double quoted: "template_url" and missing ; at the end of line
    var under700 = '<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>&w=340';
    // extra parentheses for contentwidth are not necessary
    if (contentwidth < 700)
      $('.two_images img').attr('src', under700 );
    else
      $('.two_images img').attr('src','<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>');
  }

  // run after document is ready
  $(document).ready(function() {
    imageresize();
  });
</script>
```

Dummy example:

```
<?php
// test.php
function bloginfo($a) {
  echo "http://somebloginfo.com/qwerty";
} 

$image_img_tag = array("someimagtag.jpg");

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function imageresize() {
      var contentwidth = $('#two_up').width();
      var under700 = '<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>&w=340';
      if (contentwidth < 700)
        $('.two_images img').attr('src', under700 );
      else
        $('.two_images img').attr('src','<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      imageresize();
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    test
    <div id='two_up' style="width: 400px;"></div>
    <div class="two_images">
      <img />
      <img />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope.. i just realized I am running a pretty old version of jQuery.. v1.4.4, maybe that is the problem ?

Comment: I've just added some dummy example page, please do copy-paste and check if it works for you :)